# comparar un valor e imprimirlo en un input con php y html

Tags: php, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin

tengo una base de datos con 3 campos, una matricula, un nombre y una edad, es sqli lo que uso en php y brackets, tengo 2 input text y 2 botones, un input text no se puede modificar pero quiero que ahi me imprima el nombre de la matricula que se busca, en el otro input text se coloca la matricula para que lo compare con la base de datos, el primer boton toma la matricula que se ingresa y la compara con la columna de las matriculas, si existe, imprime el nombre en el campo del nombre, el otro boton lo que hace, es eliminar esa fila en la base de datos, el proposito es tener el php en 2 archivos diferentes si es posible, por el hecho de que los separé en dos form, pero si es mejor hacer esto en un solo form, entonces estaria bien, ¿como seria el codigo de php para que esto funcione segun estas ideas? aqui el fragmento de codigo de los campos:

```html
<form action="post" action="consultar.php" id="lasAltas">
                    <ol>consultar una matricula</ol>
                   <input type="submit" value="consultar">
                   <input type="text" placeholder="matricula" name="matricula">
                   </form>
<form action="post" action="eliminar.php" id="lasAltas">
 
   <ol>nombre:</ol><input type="text" value="" readonly onmousedown="return false;" />
   <input type="submit" value="eliminar">
</form>
```

Comment: Los metodos get y post los debes pasar por el atributo "method", no "action" y en value deberás poner la variable que te pasa consultar.php (Que supongo que hará un "SELECT matricula FROM tabla WHERE matricula=$_POST['matricula']") de esta forma:  <?php echo $_POST['matricula'] ?>. Una vez tengas la variable de la matrícula podrás eliminarla, ya que debe ser un campo único y en eliminar.php debes ejecutar un "DELETE FROM tabla WHERE matricula=$_POST['matricula']".

Comment: Ese tipo de operaciones suele hacerse con Ajax, mandando los datos a un archivo PHP diferente del que tiene el formulario, para que procese los datos, devuelva la respuesta y con esa respuesta se actualiza la página sin necesidad de recargarla. Lee sobre Ajax, aquí mismo hay varios ejemplos de casos parecidos. Intenta un código y si tienes alguna dificultad podremos ayudarte. Se necesita un punto de partida de tu parte. Saludos.